# 'post__not_in' doesn't work for related posts by taxonomy (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating related posts by taxonomy. 
I have code:
(in functions.php)

```
    // Create a query for the custom taxonomy
function related_posts_by_taxonomy( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args=array() ) {
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );
// Make sure we have terms from the current post
    if ( count( $terms ) ) {
        $post_ids = get_objects_in_term( $terms[0]->term_id, $taxonomy );
        $post = get_post( $post_id );
        $post_type = get_post_type( $post );

    // Only search for the custom taxonomy on whichever post_type
    // we AREN'T currently on
    // This refers to the custom post_types you created so
    // make sure they are spelled/capitalized correctly
    if ( strcasecmp($post_type, 'colors') == 0 ) {
        $type = 'colors';
    } else {
        $type = 'colors';
    }

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, array(
            'post_type' => $type,
            'post__not_in' => array($post_id),
            'post__in' => $post_ids,
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'term' => $terms[1]->slug,
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'orderby' => 'rand'
        ) );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
}
print_r($post_id);
// Return our results in query form
return $query;
}
```

in my template single-colors.php

```
<?php $related =  related_posts_by_taxonomy( $post->ID, 'colors_tax' );
while ( $related->have_posts() ): $related->the_post(); ?>
<strong class="center block fz">
<?php echo $ncolors; ?>
</strong>
<h1 class="no-m"><?php the_title();?></h1>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The code works. But this code shows also duplicate for my post (in related posts by taxonomy).  How to eliminate it? `'post__not_in' => array($post_id)` doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, your function is completely wrong and ineffecient. I'm surpriced that it even works

Comment: You know how to fix?

Comment: Will post answer now :-)

Comment: please first of confirm post__in and post__not_in work together. i hope that's issue here. post__in and post__not_in are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I already stated, your code is completely wrong and will not work. I'm not going to go into details about your code as I would just scrap your code and start from the beginning

Here is a copy of a post I have recently done on WPSE. This is basically a copy and paste solution, the only thing here being that posts aren't radomly ordered, so you need to add random ordering into the query arguments.

Here is the post:

I would just just scrap the function above as there are several bugs in the code and is also not quite effecient. I am actually surpriced that it really works for you.

Your best solution here would be to write a complete new function. Here is want we want to do and how we are going to accomplish this

- Get the current post object on the single post page. `$post` is unreliable, so we are going to use the main query object here which we will return with `get_queried_object()`. From here we can use the post ID and post type to get other related info
- Get the terms of the current post being viewed with `wp_get_post_term()`. We will set the `fields` paremeter to only get the term ids. This returnes array of term ids can then be used in our `tax_query`
- Add in some validation to validate the user input and also sanitize the input

Lets put that all in code (*CAVEAT: This is all untested and requires at least PHP 5.4+*)

```
function get_related_posts( $taxonomy = '', $args = [] )
{
    /*
     * Before we do anything and waste unnecessary time and resources, first check if we are on a single post page
     * If not, bail early and return false
     */
    if ( !is_single() )
        return false;

    /*
     * Check if we have a valid taxonomy and also if the taxonomy exists to avoid bugs further down.
     * Return false if taxonomy is invalid or does not exist
     */
    if ( !$taxonomy ) 
        return false;

    $taxonomy = filter_var( $taxonomy, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    if ( !taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )
        return false;

    /*
     * We have made it to here, so we should start getting our stuff togther. 
     * Get the current post object to start of
     */
    $current_post = get_queried_object();

    /*
     * Get the post terms, just the ids
     */
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $current_post->ID, $taxonomy, ['fields' => 'ids'] );

    /*
     * Lets only continue if we actually have post terms and if we don't have an WP_Error object. If not, return false
     */
    if ( !$terms || is_wp_error( $terms ) )
        return false;

    /*
     * Set the default query arguments
     */
    $defaults = [
        'post_type' => $current_post->post_type,
        'post__not_in' => [$current_post->ID],
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'terms' => $terms,
                'include_children' => false
            ],
        ],
    ];

    /*
     * Validate and merge the defaults with the user passed arguments
     */
    if ( is_array( $args ) ) {
        $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    } else {
        $args = $defaults;
    }

    /*
     * Now we can query our related posts and return them
     */
    $q = get_posts( $args );

    return $q;
}
```

Now that we have a better function in place, we can use it in our single post page or content template parts depending on your exact use case. As you might have noticed, our new function `get_related_posts()` has two parameters, the first one which accepts a single taxonomy value, and the second an array of arguments. This arguments will the arguments passed to our query, so you can pass any valid array of arguments that is acceptible to `WP_Query` and `get_posts` here.

Example:

You need one post to be returned, so you can try the following: (*Please note, do not use the post type parameter or any of the taxonomy type parameters here, you might get unexpected output*)

```
if ( function_exists( 'get_related_posts' ) ) {
    $related_posts = get_related_posts( 'my_taxonomy_name', ['posts_per_page' => 1] );
    if ( $related_posts ) {
        foreach ( $related_posts as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post ); 
            // Use your template tags and html mark up as normal like
            the_title();
            the_content();
            // etc etc
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

### EDIT

From comments it seems that your PHP version is older than 5.4 which does not support the new short array syntax (`[]`), and therefor you get the dreaded WSOD. For this to work, you need change the new array syntax to the old syntax (`array()`).

You can try the following:

```
function get_related_posts( $taxonomy = '', $args = array() )
{
    /*
     * Before we do anything and waste unnecessary time and resources, first check if we are on a single post page
     * If not, bail early and return false
     */
    if ( !is_single() )
        return false;

    /*
     * Check if we have a valid taxonomy and also if the taxonomy exists to avoid bugs further down.
     * Return false if taxonomy is invalid or does not exist
     */
    if ( !$taxonomy ) 
        return false;

    $taxonomy = filter_var( $taxonomy, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    if ( !taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )
        return false;

    /*
     * We have made it to here, so we should start getting our stuff togther. 
     * Get the current post object to start of
     */
    $current_post = get_queried_object();

    /*
     * Get the post terms, just the ids
     */
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $current_post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids') );

    /*
     * Lets only continue if we actually have post terms and if we don't have an WP_Error object. If not, return false
     */
    if ( !$terms || is_wp_error( $terms ) )
        return false;

    /*
     * Set the default query arguments
     */
    $defaults = array(
        'post_type' => $current_post->post_type,
        'post__not_in' => array( $current_post->ID),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'terms' => $terms,
                'include_children' => false
            ),
        ),
    );

    /*
     * Validate and merge the defaults with the user passed arguments
     */
    if ( is_array( $args ) ) {
        $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    } else {
        $args = $defaults;
    }

    /*
     * Now we can query our related posts and return them
     */
    $q = get_posts( $args );

    return $q;
}
```

And then to use the code in templates, change to

```
if ( function_exists( 'get_related_posts' ) ) {
    $related_posts = get_related_posts( 'my_taxonomy_name', array( 'posts_per_page' => 1) );
    if ( $related_posts ) {
        foreach ( $related_posts as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post ); 
            // Use your template tags and html mark up as normal like
            the_title();
            the_content();
            // etc etc
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```